# C# Class addition to collection

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.DataSources;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace ClassReferenceStackOverFlow
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableDataSource<StockInfo1> stockData1 = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        double price = 180.00; // IBM stock price
        StockInfo1 info = new StockInfo1 { Time = time, Price = price };
        stockData1.AppendAsync(Dispatcher, info);
    }

    public class StockInfo1
    {
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double Range { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

I am fairly new to C#/WPF. Would like to have many stocks tracked/charted(here for example: IBM as StockInfo1). How can I accomplish neatly without creating ugly StockInfo2, StockInfo3 etc. ?
Been searching and trying several options but many beyond my limited knowledge of C#.
Thanks for any direction/example/code snippets in advance

Comment: Will a `List<StockInfo1>` solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just have a class for the stock

```
public class Stock
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<StockInfo> StockInfos { get; } = new ObservableCollection<StockInfo>();
}    

public class StockInfo
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Range { get; set; }
}
```

then in the main class

```
public ObservableCollection<Stock> Stocks { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Stock>();
```

no need for this `AppendAsync` stuff

Comment: Further clarification: Data comes from the exchanges(NYSE, CME, NASDAQ etc). Every second/minute real time, a quote with a  (symbol, price, time). The right collection has to be located and the quote added to the collection. In Microsoft's Dynamic Data Display ObservableData Source has an AppendAsync function that allows chart data to be added asynchronously Handy when there is lots of data coming in as a steady stream. Currently I read the symbol, identify Collection (StockInfo1, StockInfo2,  . . 20) and add datapoint to be charted.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need `StockInfo2`
just use a list or an array

```
public List<ObservableDataSource<StockInfo>> StockList = new List<ObservableDataSource<StockInfo>>();
```

then you can use

```
var info = new ObservableDataSource<StockInfo>>(new StockInfo {
    Time = DateTime.Now,
    Price = 20
})
StockList.add(info);
```

to add a new Stock to your List

or you write a function to add a new StockInfo

```
public void addStockInfo(Double price,DateTime time){
    StockList.add(new ObservableDataSource<StockInfo>>(new StockInfo {
        Time = time,
        Price = price
    });
}
```